# Increase PNG masked area on a JPG with Python Pillow (or PIL)

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to mask a jpg image using a png black/transparent mask, but due to aliasing and border blur, i always have in output a contour line of the original jpg.

Since graphical precision is not required by the task, this could be easily solved by increasing the masked area by a few pixels.

So for example if the masked area allows a centered circle of 100px, simply "extending" the circle by some pixel, would solve the problem.

Is there a way to achieve this with Pillow ?

Comment: I don't know Pillow but if you can find some morphology functions in there, a `dilate` or `erode` would likely be the one to use.

Comment: sadly i didn't find a dilate/erode function :( but i find a solution anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution; i write it down so that others may benefit if needed:

1) apply a gaussian blur to the mask. this will "expand" the borders with a shade

1b) convert in black/white colors only if needed

2) apply a transformation that converts each pixel in black or white based on a threshold. no other colors allowed

so something similar:

```
blackThreshold = 128.0
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=3))
r,g,b,a = img.split() # supposing to have a RGBA PNG
gray = Image.merge('L',(a,)) # 
gray = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<blackThreshold else 255)
```